# Fetch who voted and how many votes were given to each country

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help with query how to fetch who voted and how many votes were given to each country using MySQL?

So, I have table `voter` and `result`, you can find the dummy dataset here https://github.com/FirzaCank/Project/blob/main/SQL/Self%20Project/Vote%20Poll/Dataset%20Dummy%20voter.sql

Which `voter` [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7upEt.jpg) contains:

1. ID (INT)
2. first_name VARCHAR(10)
3. last_name VARCHAR(10)

and `result` [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8nnQ.jpg) contains:

1. voter_id (INT)
2. country VARCHAR(10)

I've tried a MySQL query like this:

```
SELECT
    country,
    CONCAT(v.first_name,' ',v.last_name,' x ',COUNT(r.voter_id)) AS votes
FROM voter v
RIGHT JOIN result r ON v.id = r.voter_id
GROUP BY country;
```

But I got an error, I'm sure this problem need something like loops but I don't really understand that stuff.

The desired output is will be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kzsu.jpg), but as far as I've tried in the above syntax it just came out with [my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ31D.jpg) which I can't display all voter in the same country, I just came out with 1 voter every 1 country.

Comment: You are encouraged to tell us which error you have (when you say: "But i got error...")

Comment: Hi, thank you for comment. I recently updated my error with added explanation and image helps.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Hi, thank you for comment. Sorry for that, I'm new here and I'm not used to it so thank you for your advice. i will not repeat this mistake again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    country,
    group_concat(votes,',') as votes
FROM
(
   SELECT
      country,
      CONCAT(v.first_name,' ',v.last_name,' x ',COUNT(r.voter_id)) AS votes
   FROM voter v
   RIGHT JOIN result r ON v.id = r.voter_id
   GROUP BY country,first_name,last_name
) x
GROUP BY country;
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9bb5e54d5446a24c6433f9213f93597e)

First your query give an error. This one:

> "SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated
> column '...first_name' which is not functionally
> dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
> sql_mode=only_full_group_by"

This error, and how to handle it, is epxlained here: [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

This means that all fields that are not used in an aggregate function, you be mentioned in the GROUP BY.

Because your desire is that the output only contains 1 line per country the [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) function is added on the result.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, (probably a bit more optimal on big data, because aggregation happens over single table):

```
select country, group_concat(concat(first_name, ' ', last_name, ' x ', c) order by c desc)
from (  
  select country, voter_id, count(*) c 
  from result
  group by country, voter_id
) x
join voter on id = voter_id
group by country;
```